# what is my program not reading from file after i close it and then run it again for reading from the file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have written a program that stores date and time in a custom data type and then stores it in a binary file. Everything works perfectly if I compile and run the program in DevC++ 5.11 (shortcut <kbd>F11</kbd>). My program is able to store data in the file and then read it as long as I don't close the program. However, if I close the program and then open the file again for reading, it only shows the first day that I entered and doesn't show the rest of it. Please tell me what I need to do to fix this.

Here is my DevC++ 5.11 code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char s=' ';

struct date{
    int day;
    string month;
    int year;
};

struct time{
    int hr;
    int min;
};

class entry{
    private:
        int sno;
        date d;
        time t;

    public:

        void initsno(){
            sno=0;
        }

        void getdate(){
            cout << "\nEnter the date : ";
            cout << "\nDay : ";
            cin >> d.day;
            cout << "Month : ";
            cin >> d.month;
            cout << "Yeay :";
            cin >> d.year;      
        }

        void gettime(){
            cout << "\n\nEnter time : ";
            cout << "\nHours :";
            cin >> t.hr;
            cout << "Minutes :";
            cin >> t.min;
        }   

        void showdate(){
            cout << "\n\nDate is : ";
            cout << d.day << s << d.month << s << d.year << endl << endl;
        }

        void showtime(){
            cout << "\n\nTime is :";
            cout << t.hr << ":" << t.min << endl << endl;
        }           
};

int main(){

    //declaring variables
    char c='y', l;
    string filename;
    entry e, e2;
    ofstream filew;
    ifstream filer; 

    cout << "******Time sheet calculator******" << endl << endl;

    //getting file name begins
    cout << "Enter the name of file you want to create : ";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "\nThe file name is : " << filename << endl;
    //getting file name over

    e.initsno();    //initializing the entry serial number

    //creating and opening file
    filew.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app);
    //file association operation successful

    if (!filew)
        cout << "\nCan't open file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "continue write operation\n";

    //getting date
    e.getdate();

    cout << "\nDo you want to write to file? :";
    cin >> l;

    if (l == 'y')
    {
        //Entering time
        while (c == 'y')
        {
            e.gettime();
            filew.write((char*)&e, sizeof(e));
            cout << "\nFile write operation successful.\n";
            cout << "\nDo you wish to continue? :";
            cin >> c;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "\nContinue reading...\n";

    //closing file
    filew.close();

    cout << "\nReading file...\n";

    //opening file for reading
    filer.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::in);

    if (!filer)
        cout << "\nCan't open file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "continue read operation\n";

    while (filer.read((char*)&e2, sizeof(e2)))
    {
        cout << "\nDisplaying file data...\n";
        e2.showdate();
        e2.showtime();
    }

    cout << "\n\nFile IO successful...";

    filer.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I mean to ask why is my program not reading from file properly.

Comment: Your `date` struct contains a `string` member. You can't `write()`/`read()` a `string` as-is, since the character data is stored elsewhere in memory. You need to *serialize* the string instead (ie, save its `size()` value followed by its actual character data). Otherwise, use a fixed `char[]` array instead.

Comment: Hey Remy, Thanks for getting back to me. How do i serialize string?

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau . I think serialization is what i need to do to fix it. I will try it and give it a go. I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date` struct contains a `string` member. You can't `write()`/`read()` a `string` as-is, since the character data is (usually<sup>1</sup>) stored elsewhere in memory.

<sup>1: not taking Short String Optimization into account, in which case small amounts of character data are actually stored directly in the `string` object.</sup>

Use a fixed `char[]` array instead of a `string`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct date{
    int day;
    char month[10];
    int year;
};

struct time{
    int hr;
    int min;
};

class entry{
    private:
        int sno;
        date d;
        time t;

    public:

        void initsno(){
            sno=0;
        }

        void getdate(){
            cout << "\nEnter the date : ";
            cout << "\nDay : ";
            cin >> d.day;
            cout << "Month : ";
            cin.get(d.month, sizeof(d.month));
            cout << "Year :";
            cin >> d.year;      
        }

        void gettime(){
            cout << "\n\nEnter time : ";
            cout << "\nHours :";
            cin >> t.hr;
            cout << "Minutes :";
            cin >> t.min;
        }   

        void showdate(){
            cout << "\n\nDate is : ";
            cout << d.day << s << d.month << s << d.year << endl << endl;
        }

        void showtime(){
            cout << "\n\nTime is :";
            cout << t.hr << ":" << t.min << endl << endl;
        }           
};

int main(){

    //declaring variables
    char c;
    string filename;
    entry e, e2;
    ofstream filew;
    ifstream filer; 

    cout << "******Time sheet calculator******" << endl << endl;

    //getting file name begins
    cout << "Enter the name of file you want to create : ";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "\nThe file name is : " << filename << endl;
    //getting file name over

    e.initsno();    //initializing the entry serial number

    //creating and opening file
    filew.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::app);
    //file association operation successful

    if (!filew)
        cout << "\nCan't open file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "continue write operation\n";

    //getting date
    e.getdate();

    cout << "\nDo you want to write to file? :";
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 'y')
    {
        //Entering time
        do
        {
            e.gettime();
            filew.write((char*)&e, sizeof(e));
            cout << "\nFile write operation successful.\n";
            cout << "\nDo you wish to continue? :";
            cin >> c;
        }
        while (c == 'y');
    }
    else
        cout << "\nContinue reading...\n";

    //closing file
    filew.close();

    cout << "\nReading file...\n";

    //opening file for reading
    filer.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

    if (!filer)
        cout << "\nCan't open file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "continue read operation\n";

    while (filer.read((char*)&e2, sizeof(e2)))
    {
        cout << "\nDisplaying file data...\n";
        e2.showdate();
        e2.showtime();
    }

    cout << "\n\nFile IO successful...";

    filer.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you need to *serialize* the `string` (ie, save its `size()` value followed by its actual character data), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct date{
    int day;
    string month;
    int year;

    void read(istream &is) {
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&day), sizeof(day));
        size_t size;
        if (is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size)))
        {
            month.resize(size);
            is.read(&month[0], size);
        }
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&year), sizeof(year));
    }

    void write(ostream &os) const {
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&day), sizeof(day));
        size_t size = month.size();
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
        os.write(month.c_str(), size);
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&year), sizeof(year));
    }
};

istream& operator>>(istream &is, date &d)
{
    d.read(is);
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const date &d)
{
    d.write(os);
    return os;
}

struct time{
    int hr;
    int min;

    void read(istream &is)
    {
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hr), sizeof(hr));
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&min), sizeof(min));
    }

    void write(ostream &os) const
    {
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&hr), sizeof(hr));
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&min), sizeof(min));
    }
};

istream& operator>>(istream &is, time &t)
{
    t.read(is);
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const time &t)
{
    t.write(os);
    return os;
}

class entry{
    private:
        int sno;
        date d;
        time t;

    public:

        void initsno(){
            sno=0;
        }

        void getdate(){
            cout << "\nEnter the date : ";
            cout << "\nDay : ";
            cin >> d.day;
            cout << "Month : ";
            cin >> d.month;
            cout << "Yeay :";
            cin >> d.year;      
        }

        void gettime(){
            cout << "\n\nEnter time : ";
            cout << "\nHours :";
            cin >> t.hr;
            cout << "Minutes :";
            cin >> t.min;
        }   

        void showdate(){
            cout << "\n\nDate is : ";
            cout << d.day << s << d.month << s << d.year << endl << endl;
        }

        void showtime(){
            cout << "\n\nTime is :";
            cout << t.hr << ":" << t.min << endl << endl;
        }

        void read(istream &is) {
            is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sno), sizeof(sno));
            d.read(is);
            t.read(is);
        }

        void write(ostream &os) const {
            os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sno), sizeof(sno));
            d.write(os);
            t.write(os);
        }
};

istream& operator>>(istream &is, entry &e)
{
    e.read(is);
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const entry &e)
{
    e.write(os);
    return os;
}

int main(){

    //declaring variables
    char c;
    string filename;
    entry e, e2;
    ofstream filew;
    ifstream filer; 

    cout << "******Time sheet calculator******" << endl << endl;

    //getting file name begins
    cout << "Enter the name of file you want to create : ";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "\nThe file name is : " << filename << endl;
    //getting file name over

    e.initsno();    //initializing the entry serial number

    //creating and opening file
    filew.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::app);
    //file association operation successful

    if (!filew)
        cout << "\nCan't open file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "continue write operation\n";

    //getting date
    e.getdate();

    cout << "\nDo you want to write to file? :";
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 'y')
    {
        //Entering time
        do
        {
            e.gettime();
            filew << e;
            cout << "\nFile write operation successful.\n";
            cout << "\nDo you wish to continue? :";
            cin >> c;
        }
        while (c == 'y');
    }
    else
        cout << "\nContinue reading...\n";

    //closing file
    filew.close();

    cout << "\nReading file...\n";

    //opening file for reading
    filer.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

    if (!filer)
        cout << "\nCan't open file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "continue read operation\n";

    while (filer >> e2)
    {
        cout << "\nDisplaying file data...\n";
        e2.showdate();
        e2.showtime();
    }

    cout << "\n\nFile IO successful...";

    filer.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much!!! Also can you suggest any resource like a book where i can learn file handling in c++ in depth. because i dont know serialization and  file handling.

Comment: I tried the top one because its easier for me but its not running properly. It stops after you enter the day in date. Can you help me out?

Comment: can you explain what this code is doing in the read function for struct date
```
if (is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size)))
        {
            month.resize(size);
            is.read(&month[0], size);
        }

'''

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma "*I tried the top one because its easier for me but its not running properly*" - what does your input look like? "*can you explain what this code is doing*" - a `std::string` is variable-length, so the code writes a `size_t` in front of the character data specifying the string's length. That code is reading the length value first, then allocating the string to that length, and then reading the character data into the allocated memory.

Comment: The first one just stops soon as i enter the date the first time say 1. And i want to know for the second one shouldn't you initialize size_t size with the size of the string first and then reinterpret_cast it? and what would is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size),sizeof(size)) return in the if statement, that is what would it check for? would it return a null pointer if there is no string and a valid pointer if there is a string stored in the file?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma I asked you to show the *actual input*, not a *description* of the input. "*shouldn't you initialize size_t size with the size of the string first*" - that is exactly what the code does when it `read()`'s the `size_t` from the file. The value of the `size_t` was written to the file. "*what would is.read(...) return in the if statement*" - it checks whether `read()` successfully read in `sizeof(size_t)` number of bytes. `read()` returns a reference to the `istream`, which reports its state when evaluated in a boolean context. Seems you need to brush up on stream fundamentals.

Comment: Now i am understanding it. thanks. I haven't really learnt about streams at all i am doing that now to learn this. So the input for the first code is ptime.dat and 1 like this:
Enter the name of the file you want to create: ptime.dat
Enter the date: 1
and the program stops right after that.

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma are you entering a space or pressing enter after entering the 1?

Comment: Yes i press enter after the 1 and then it displays the couts and stops execution. for the second code shouldn't we reinterpret_cast int day back to <int*> instead of <char *> because day is an int type?