# How to serialize an object that might contain other objects of a user-defined class in c++ without using any special header files?

Tags: c++, serialization

I'm making a small program that contains a user defined class that contains obects object of struct type date and time. The struct date contains a string type. How can i serialize the containing object entry so as to be able to store the entry object in a file as well as to read from it in c++?
Here is my minimal code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#define s ' ' //defining space character

using namespace std;


struct date{
int day;
string month;
int year;
};


struct time{
int hr;
int min;
};

class entry{
private:
    date d;
    time t;
    int sno=0;

public:
    void incrementsno(){++sno;}



void getdate(){      //This function gets date
        cout<<"\nEnter the date : ";
        cout<<"\nDay : ";
        cin>>d.day;
        cout<<"Month : ";
        cin>>d.month;
        cout<<"Year :";
        cin>>d.year;        
    }

    void gettime(){     //This function gets time
    cout<<"\n\nEnter time : ";
    cout<<"\nHours :";
    cin>>t.hr;
    cout<<"Minutes :";
    cin>>t.min;
    }   

};

int main(){

//declaring variables
char c;
string filename;
entry e;
ifstream filer; 
ofstream filew;

//getting file name begins
cout<<"Enter the name of file you want to create : ";
cin>>filename;
cout<<"\nThe file name is : "<<filename<<endl;
//getting file name over



//creating and opening file
filew.open(filename.c_str(),ios::binary|ios::out|ios::app);
//file association operation successful


cout<<"\nDo you want to write to file? : ";
cin>>c; 

if(c=='y')//Entering date and time
{       
    do{
        e.getdate();
        e.gettime();
        filew.write((char*)&e,sizeof(e));
        cout<<"\nFile write operation successful.\n";
        e.incrementsno(); 
        cout<<"\nDo you wish to continue? :";
        cin>>c;
    }
    while(c=='y');
}
else
    cout<<"\nReading file...\n";

filew.close();

filer.open(filename.c_str(),ios::binary|ios::in);   //opening file for reading 


while(filer.read((char*)&e,sizeof(e)))
{
    e.showdate();
    e.showtime();
}

cout<<"\n\nFile IO successful...";


filer.close();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing the `struct`, put the definition of it in the question.

Comment: Here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355643/what-is-my-program-not-reading-from-file-after-i-close-it-and-then-run-it-again

Comment: Edit your question and put a [mcve] in it.  I did't see a `char[]` in the `struct`s in the code you linked to.

Comment: Here is my minimal code https://filebin.net/ddrv9g15o8d7lgez/minimal?t=5d8lu59r

Comment: I removed the char[] and changed the month variable to string type. and i need to serialize the variable e of class entry type to write it in a binary file and then reconstruct it. Please let me know how i can do it as i have tried to find resources to learn serialization of objects in C++ online but couldn't find any good ones.

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61645684/edit) your question and put a [mcve] in it. At the very least, put the definition of the `struct` you are talking about **in the question**.

Comment: just added the example code. hope this is helpful!

Comment: Much better. I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for being patient!

Comment: I got carried away ... I will have something to show that I hope can help in a bit.

Comment: I have to chill for Tonight, but I'll try to give you something to work with Tomorrow.

Comment: sounds good. Thanks. I don't have any idea how serialization works all i know is we convert an object to a linear code to store it. So please elaborate everything. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-working, halfmeasure streaming framework based on the comments. It does NOT work - it's something to work with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Date {
    int day;
    std::string month;
    int year;
};

// Date serializing support:

// stream out a Date to a generic stream (like a file)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& d) {
    return os << d.day << '\n' << d.month << '\n' << d.year << '\n';
}

// read a Date from a generic stream (like a file)
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Date& d) {
    return is >> d.day >> d.month >> d.year;
}

// Date adapters for human interaction - only holds references to "real" objects
struct DateUIout {
    explicit DateUIout(const Date& d) : date(d) {}
    // DateUIout(const Date&) = delete; // not copyable - but made it explicitly
    // clear

    // holds a reference to the Date struct we'd like to work with
    // and an output stream for asking the user questions if needed
    const Date& date;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DateUIout& dui) {
    const Date& d = dui.date; // alias to the Date we'd like to work with
    return os << "Day: " << d.day << " Month: " << d.month << " Year: " << d.year
              << '\n';
}

struct DateUIin {
    explicit DateUIin(Date& d, std::ostream& qs = std::cout) :
        date(d), questions(qs) {}
    DateUIin(const Date&) = delete; // not copyable - but made it explicitly clear

    Date& date;
    std::ostream& questions; // used for printing questions to humans
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, DateUIin& dui) {
    Date& d = dui.date; // alias to the Date we'd like to work with
    dui.questions << "Enter the date:\n"
                  << " Day: ";
    is >> d.day;
    dui.questions << " Month: ";
    is >> d.month;
    dui.questions << " Year: ";
    return is >> d.year;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Time {
    int hr;
    int min;
};

// Time serializing support: (much like everything in Date)

// stream out a Time
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Time& t) {
    return os << t.hr << '\n' << t.min << '\n';
}

// read a Time from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Time& t) {
    return is >> t.hr >> t.min;
}

// Time adapter for human interaction - only holds references to "real" objects
struct TimeUI {
    explicit TimeUI(Time& t, std::ostream& qs = std::cout) : tim(t), questions(qs) {}
    Time& tim;
    std::ostream& questions;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TimeUI& tui) {
    Time& t = tui.tim;
    return os << "Hour: " << t.hr << ' ' << t.min << '\n';
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TimeUI& tui) {
    Time& t = tui.tim;
    tui.questions << "Enter the time:\n Hour: ";
    is >> t.hr;
    tui.questions << " Minute: ";
    return is >> t.min;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Timestamp {
    Date date{};
    Time time{};
};

// Timestamp serializing support:

// stream out a Timestamp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Timestamp& ts) {
    return os << ts.date << ts.time;
}

// read a Timestamp from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Timestamp& ts) {
    return is >> ts.date >> ts.time;
}

// Timestamp adapter for human interaction - only holds references to "real" objects
struct TimestampUIout {
    TimestampUIout(const Timestamp& Ts) : ts(Ts) {}
    // TimestampUIout(const TimestampUI&) = delete;

    Timestamp& ts;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TimestampUIout& tsui) {
    return os << DateUIout(tsui.ts.date) << TimeUI(tsui.ts.time, os);
}

struct TimestampUIin {
    TimestampUI(Timestamp& Ts, std::ostream& qs = std::cout) :
        ts(Ts), questions(qs) {}
    TimestampUI(const TimestampUI&) = delete;

    Timestamp& ts;
    std::ostream& questions;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TimestampUIin& tsui) {
    DateUIin dui(tsui.ts.date, tsui.questions);
    TimeUI tui(tsui.ts.time, tsui.questions);
    return is >> dui >> tui;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
    Timestamp tmp;
    TimestampUI tsui(tmp, std::cout); // bind UI adapter to the Timestamp

    std::vector<Timestamp> timestamps;

    while(std::cin >> tsui) {      // use UI adapter
        timestamps.push_back(tmp); // store a raw Timestamp
    }

    // print collected timestamps - using adapter
    for(const Timestamp& ts : timestamps) {
        std::cout << TimestampUIout(ts);
    }
    // print collected timestamps - as they would be streamed to a file
    for(const Timestamp& ts : timestamps) {
        std::cout << ts;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, lots of new things for me. im a complete beginner in file handling. Will take me some time to figure out what is going on. Might ask you some more questions. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma I was in a bit of a hurry and should perhaps have shortened it down into something minimal that's actually working instead. If you can't make heads or tails out of this, just comment and I'll replace it with something with a lot less code.

Comment: ive been trying to find a book where i can learn serialization from zero. but this is one of the topics that is hard to find. can you recommend any book or resources to learn serialization @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma There are some good books in the FAQ so you might find one there that might be useful - but serialization isn't that magic really. Doing it really well might be a bit complicated though. You could start with a real world serialization problem and work it out from there. Streaming to/from files is a good start.